# Jquery Select meta[property=og:image]?

Tags: jquery, select, meta, facebook-opengraph

I want to select in Jquery the main photo in a web page, I just have the url page.
so I decided to use the meta written for Facebook sharing.

I want to select the content of : 
meta property="og:image" content="http://blablabla.jpg"

I wrote this, but it doesn't work:
    $("meta[property=og:image]").attr("content");

Any ideas ?
Thank you

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`$('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content')`

http://jsfiddle.net/ZxmCw/

Comment: It's minor but since you can have multiple og:image tags I added in: $('meta[property="og:image"]:eq(0)').attr('content'). jUQery selectors FTW

Answer (score 8):

`:image` is parsed as a pseudo-selector. I think you need quotes around "og:image"