# Goquery Select meta[property=og:image]?

Tags: go, goquery

**Goquery** [Syntax-wise, it is as close as possible to jQuery, with the same function names when possible, and that warm and fuzzy chainable interface.](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery)

```
doc.Find("meta[property='og:image']").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    fmt.Fprintln("og data=", s)
})
```

Apparently not close enough to that [j-thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977652/jquery-select-metaproperty-ogimage).

How can you get the og data in a webpage from goquery?

Answer (score 6):

Just figured it out - hope this helps someone else out there

```
doc.Find("meta").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    op, _ := s.Attr("property")
    con, _ := s.Attr("content")
    if op == "og:image" {
        fmt.Fprintln("og data=", con)
    }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this and I found an other way.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

func main() {
    baseURL := `REPLACE_WITH_URL`

    resp, err := http.Get(baseURL)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromResponse(resp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    imgURL, found := doc.Find(`meta[property="og:image"]`).Attr("content")

    fmt.Println(imgURL, found)
}
```

Comment: I like this too!